# How can I have a given processor finish tasks one after one?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, mpi, shared-memory

In Python, I am running a multiprocessor based computation using **mpi4py**. In my code, I let **every processor do a number of tasks** (let’s **assume each processor does 5 tasks**, i.e. number = 5). All these tasks are **memory intensive**. To make sure that a processor doesn’t run out of memory, I would like to have a situation where the processor finishes one task and then moves to the other task(s).

My code is structured as below.

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD 
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

count = 0
for i in range(1, size):
    if rank == i:
        for j in range(5):
            count = count + 1
            res = func(count)
            comm.send(res, dest=0, tag=count)
```

In the above example, **‘func’** is the **user defined function which does the memory intensive task** (lets assume that count is the argument of that function.)

If we take processor 1 (rank==1) as an example, then five different tasks are running on it (viz., func(1), func(2), func(3), func(4), func(5)). I suppose I should make sure that func(1) finishes running on processor 1 and then func(2) runs on processor 1 (while func(2) … func(5) are waiting, and so on) (to make sure that processor 1 does not run into memory errors). I will be thankful if someone can tell me how I can do that.

Comment: The simplest solution is to have each processor do one task that runs a loop in which it sequentially does its five jobs.

Comment: @Linuxos: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave a very simplified version of the actual code that I am presently working on. From what I understand, your suggestion will require me to change the user defined function 'func' in such a manner that it will contain a for loop which will loop over the concerned arguments. I am afraid the present version of the function 'func' may not allow me to do that.

Comment: I'm still pretty sure that'll be the easiest way. What makes it difficult to enclose the body of the function in a loop?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - it looks like the code as currently written does what you want it to do. func(1) will run on processor 1, then it will send the results to processor 0, then func(2) will run on processor 1, etc.

Comment: @Linuxios: In the example that I have given here, I am presenting a very simplified version of my code. In actuality, I am dealing with quite a few functions (15 different functions), each function takes eight separate arrays as arguments. The choice of each function is defined by the counter (i.e., the value of the variable count.) Given this, I think it will be a more complicated task to modify each function and then synchronize with the counter.

Comment: @user2004343: If you are sure that is the case, then that would be very good for me. The crux of my worry is a scenario where I let one processor (say processor 1) do five tasks (each task requires 3 GB memory) and then all five tasks run on the processor at the same time (requiring 3*5 = 15 GB of memory, which will be bad). Again, if you are sure that task 2 will run on processor 1 only after task 1 is finished (task 3 will run after task 2 is finished and same for tasks 4 and 5) then that will be very pleasing news for me.

Comment: @SiddTheKid: Unless I'm not understanding, it's still simple. Define a new function called `wrapper` (or whatever), dispatch that to each processor with a range of values for `count` that that processor is responsible for, and in `wrapper`, iterate over that range and dispatch, sequentially, to the other 15 functions as indicated by count.

Comment: Yes, in your current setup each processor will only run one task at a time. It has to complete func(1) before it moves to the next iteration, at which point it will run func(2), so on and so forth. If you want to verify this, remove the lines that say res = func(count), comm.send(res, dest=0, tag=count), and instead just put: print 'Processor %d is running process %d'%(i,j). If the task numbers come out in order then it is running properly